# Position off center jQuery positon

Tags: jquery, position, modal-dialog

I'm trying to position my dialog 100 px off center.  Is this possible with the jQuery positioning tools, or do I need to find the size of the window and position manually?

```
$dialog.dialog("option", "position", "center+100");
```

Comment: Yup, it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: "center+100", "center 100"

Comment: @Lumpy, [please show the code you have actually tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: Update your question to include the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery Ui dialog there is a option called [position()](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position)

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "position", [450,200] );//example measurements
```

if you want to be more generic about  all monitor sizes use `$(window).height()` and `width()`

and add 100 px to them.

Or simply

```
$('#selector').dialog({
  position: ['top', 100]   //100 px down from the top.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split center into horizontal and vertical positioning.

```
$dialog.dialog("option", "position", "center+100 center+100");
```